# How to check if the response array exists and there's some content other than...?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I've got a bash script and I'm trying to perform a command based on a JSON response.

I can have back 3 types of response which I store in the `content` variable:

1st type (repo doesn't exist):

```json
{
    "message": "The repo doesn't exist"
}
```

2nd type (repo exists but there's no content):

```json
[
    {
        "name": ".dotfile"
    },
    {
        "name": ".anotherdotfile"
    },
    {
        "name": "README.md"
    },
]
```

3rd type (repo exists and there's a content):

```json
[
    {
        "name": ".dotfile"
    },
    {
        "name": ".anotherdotfile"
    },
    {
        "name": "README.md"
    },
    {
        "name": "myscript.sh"
    },
    {
        "name": "anotherscript.sh"
    },
    {
        "name": "anotherfile.sh"
    },
]
```

In my script I have loop like this:

```bash
#/bin/bash

for repo_name in "${repos_name[@]}"; do
    content=$(curl -s http://example.com/$repo_name)
    
    # Here I would like to check if the response is of the 3rd type.
    # So, if it's an array with at least 1 object with value's name
    # which not start from "." or equal to "README.md".
    # In that case I would perform a command

done
```

Basically, I would like to check if a repo exist and it has some content apart from the dot files and the README.

I tried to use `jq` tool but I don't know how to correctly filter the content to perform the check.

How can I achieve that result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will evaluate to `false` given your first two inputs, and `true` given the third one. use it as condition in a `if` or `select` expression if your "command" lives inside jq. Otherwise, you could use jq's `--exit-status` (or `-e`) flag to set its exit status to `1` or `0`, which you can capture and process in the invoking shell either by assigning `$?` to a variable, or by directly using the invocation in an `if` statement.

```
any(arrays[]; .name | . == "README.md" or startswith(".") | not)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vku_4KL9kTO)